# Grails Spring Security request parameters

Tags: grails, spring-security

i'm using grails 1.3.8 and spring security plugin. 
I want to get request parameters before was redirect to *auth*. (for example, i want to get

> /mypage

, but i am not loggedin, so it redirected to

> /login

page) 
How can i get request parameters for

> /mypage

in my case (code below)

My login controller has:

```
def auth = {
        redirect(controller: 'consumer', action: 'login', params: params)
    }
```

and my ConsumerController:

```
def login = {
        def config = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig

        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
            redirect uri: config.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
            return
        }

        String postUrl = "${request.contextPath}${config.apf.filterProcessesUrl}"
        [postUrl: postUrl, rememberMeParameter: config.rememberMe.parameter]
    }
```

In this case after i am logged in, i have blank page.

UPDATE: now i look at side

> request.session.getAttribute('SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY')

but i don't know, how to redirect with parameters from

> defaultSavedRequest

on another page, for example,

> /mypageDescription

Comment: Did you tested with the default controller generated by the Spring Security (command s2-quickstart)? I know that when you hit a page with params in the url, the flow automatically will redirect to the same url after login.

Comment: I have this controllers and I want to save parameters from post request or to get them from spring security. This is my question. I know that default spring security controller works well :)

Comment: Redirect must be to another page, i want to save parameters from post

Comment: Ok, so your flow is: hit mypage, send to login, send to defaultTargetUrl instead of mypage, am I wright?

Comment: Yes, after login succeed send to url (may be defaultTargetUrl, but i'm not shure)

Comment: I suggest you not to use `request.session.getAttribute('SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY')` but to inject requesCache in your controller and obtain the savedRequest with removeRequest(). Than I think (but not tested) you can redirect calling 'redirect(uri: 'yourNewUrl', params: savedRequest.parameterMap)'